# How to resolve this error in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I know this will be marked as a duplicate post as there were some questions about this error. I've gone through those, but got no idea how to resolve it. Please help me. Here is the error message.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "iptrace.py", line 21, in mbt
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(tget, tget+" lives in "+jd["city"]+", "+jd["region"]+" "+jd["country"])
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import json
import urllib
import sys

def wmi():
    uip = urllib.urlopen("http://www.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nst/tools/ip.php").read()
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Whats my IP", "Your IP is "+uip)
def mbt():

    global ew1

    tget = ew1.get().strip()

    jd = json.load(urllib.urlopen("http://ipinfo.io/"+tget+"/geo"))

    if tget == "":
      tkMessageBox.showerror(tget, "Type a IP Please")
    else:
      tkMessageBox.showinfo(tget, tget+" lives in "+jd["city"]+", "+jd["region"]+" "+jd["country"]) 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk()

    root.title("-|IP2Location|-")

    textFrame = Frame(root)

    entryLabel = Label(textFrame)
    entryLabel["text"] = "IP :"
    entryLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

    ew1 = Entry(textFrame)
    ew1["width"] = 24
    ew1.pack(side=LEFT)

    textFrame.pack()

    bmi = Button(root, text="Whats my IP", command=wmi)
    bmi.pack()

    bs = Button(root, text="Submit", command=mbt)
    bs.pack()

    def enterPress(event):
      mbt()

    root.bind("<Return>", enterPress)

    def enterPress(event):
      exit()
      sys.exit(0)

    root.bind("<Escape>", enterPress)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error, as stated in the Traceback is located in:

```
else:
      tkMessageBox.showinfo(tget, tget+" lives in \
          "+jd["city"]+", "+jd["region"]+" "+jd["country"])
```

So what's causing the problem is you're using the `+` sign for two different types, one being a `string` and the other `NoneType` (i.e. has no value).

So what you'll need to do is change the predefined variables to strings using `str(var)` that you're trying to concatenate within that statement. Only then it'll run without issue.

Comment: I'm still confused. Can you point me the exact changes to be made.

Comment: I'm assuming it's the `tget` variable. After your `else:` statement add `print(type(tget))` what do you get?

Comment: Shows NameError: name 'tget' is not defined

Comment: Are you making sure it's indented properly?

Comment: Made the following changes `else:
      print(type(tget)) 
      tkMessageBox.showinfo(tget, tget+" lives in "+jd["city"]+", "+jd["region"]+" "+jd["country"])`    Still same error _TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects_

Comment: Yes that wasn't to fix the problem, I should've been more clear. What is the type of `tget` you're getting from the print command?

Comment: Solved the problem. It was actually an error due to the output from the website used to fetch the data. Thanks for helping me out.